# Destination Array not long enough?

Tags: c#, list, locking

I have a class with the following method:

```
public List<Bike> bikesCopy 
{
     get 
     { 
       List<Bike> bs;
       lock (_bikes) bs = new List<Bike>(_bikes);
       return bs;
     }
}
```

Which makes a copy of another list, `private List<Bike> _bikes;`

The strange thing now is, that I get the following error:

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? Can you update the question with the exception stack trace and point out the exact code line where it is thrown?

Comment: Yes, it is the following message (sorry for the mess):

`at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List'1.CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
   at MyGame.Player.get_bikesCopy()`

Comment: Did you every get to the root cause of this problem?  I am running into something similar.

Comment: If you didn't resolve this, I believe the problem could be that you have not put a lock around the _bikes.Add(_) method (or maybe another List method). This is because the Add method is not thread safe in a List. Anyway, hope that helps if anyone gets the same problem

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I would say the error lies in the object **_bikes** not being thread safe. As commented, somewhere there is a modify of the **_bikes** object that is not being lock'ed.

It is a split second error where the variable **bs** is set up to a size X when the size of **_bikes** is measured. In the next split second as it is about to fill the list, the **_bikes** object has increased in size giving the error.

So go over your code. Find all references of your **_bikes** object and make sure they are thread safe handled (with lock).

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I accidentally clicked on downvote but I actually wanted to upvote and now I cannot un-vote anymore :-/ Sorry!!

Comment: That is ok. The worst is when you get down voted and have no clue to as of why.

Comment: Yeah, I got a "fan" a couple of days ago (18 downvotes within 2 minutes) and learned about the anti-serial-downvoting bot. I really like that bot :-)
P.S.: The website says, if you edit the answer, I can undo the downvote again.

Comment: What did you edit?! I am confused... However: I like bikes :-)

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs because multiple threads are adding items in a single list. Lists are by default not a thread-safe solution. In a multi-threaded code, it is only recommended to read from a list, and not write to it.

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/):

> If you are only reading from a shared collection, then you can use the
>   classes in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Better use a thread-safe solution like [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netcore-3.1) namespace which provides implementations like [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1), [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1), [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1), [ConcurrentStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=netcore-3.1) etc.

For example:

```
public ConcurrentBag<Bike> bikesCopy 
{
     get => new ConcurrentBag<Bike>()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well you could try:

```
using System.Linq; //ToList() is an extension function defined here
...
lock(_bikes)
    return _bikes.ToList();
```

The details of the exception are discussed here: [Why doesn't a foreach loop work in certain cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167333/why-doesnt-a-foreach-loop-work-in-certain-cases)

Comment: I am not capable using LINQ, as it is not whitelisted on my framework.... Anyway, it doesn't answer my problem either :)

Comment: You can't use LINQ?!?!? I'd quit that job as soon as I found that out!

Comment: Not sure why, but `.ToList()` works great versus `new List<T>(YourList)`, which always throws an exception.

Comment: @JamesM It's the line  `_items = new T[capacity];` in the source code for List<T> (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html) which makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more a research comment.

I ran into the same problem and did a quick test.
I tried with the code below and could not get this code to throw the `ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough`. But when I remove the `.ToList()` from the line

```
return allLines.ToList().ToArray();
```

it immediately crashes.

This is the demo code and even the IDE tells me, I should remove the `ToList()` call as it seems redundant.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main() {

            List<string> thelist = new List<string>();

            Thread producer = new Thread(() => {
                while (true) {
                    thelist.Add("a" + DateTime.Now);
                }
            });

            Thread transformer = new Thread(() => {
                while (true) {
                    string[] thearray = thelist.ToList().ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine(thearray.Length);
                }
            });
            producer.Start();
            transformer.Start();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I really wonder, why it would not crash, as the List is also backed by an array.