# Getting exception when working with list and parallel loops

Tags: c#, arrays, list, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I have written a code like following below:

```
Parallel.ForEach(filteredList, (f) =>
{
    var conditionMatchCount = itm.AsParallel().Max(i =>
        // One point if ID matches
        ((i.ItemID == f.ItemID) ? 1 : 0) +
        // One point if ID and QuantitySold match
        ((i.ItemID == f.ItemID && i.QuantitySold == f.QuantitySold) ? 1 : 0)
    );
    // Item is missing
    if (conditionMatchCount == 0)
    {
        ListToUpdate.Add(f);
        missingList.Add(f);
    }
    // Item quantity is different
    else if (conditionMatchCount == 1)
    {
        ListToUpdate.Add(f);
    }
});
```

I basically have two lists:

```
// itm - list whos data comes from DB 
// filteredList => whos data comes from an external source
```

What I'm trying to achieve with the code above is to compare the two lists

and see which items from filteredList (new one) are not present in "itm" list...

If they are not present in "itm" list, they are added to

```
missingList.Add(f);
```

Also any items that have different QuantitySold property different than the one in "itm" list, I add them as well to ListToUpdate;

The error that I'm getting here is on the following line:

```
else if (conditionMatchCount == 1)
{
    ListToUpdate.Add(f);
}
```

And it says:

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length and the array's lower bounds

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. Guys,  both ListToUpdate and Missing list are plain simple lists, is that whats causing the issue here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destination Array not long enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362023/destination-array-not-long-enough)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `List<T>` with multiple threads. They aren't thread safe.

Consider using a collection from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For my own benefit, would using a `lock` be an option as well? Agree that changing the datatype is best but if this was not possible...

Comment: yea thats possible but things could suffer.

Comment: @Equalsk good point... I'd mess up the entire code if i Converted it to concurrent bag or some other ..

Comment: depending how you want to consume from it @User987, you could use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `ConcurrentStack<T>`.

Comment: @DanielA.White which one of these is the fastest when performance comes in question ?

Comment: @User987 you have to test it. i can't reasonably answer that.

Comment: @DanielA.White okay thx ! =) I'll accept ur asnwer as correct one

Comment: @DanielA.White P.S. I thought that because i use PLINQ that the piece of code I wrote is thread safe... Apparently not?

Comment: @User987 PLINQ only does certain things. it does not make unthread safe code thread safe.