# Parallel Foreach array from async method

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am getting an error when looping array from async method as Parallel.
When debuging, I can see count of the resultsArray is 11.
But after stepping over a few times, it showed me "Source array was not long enough"
Can I please get what the issue of my code?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(int id)
{
   List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    Result[] resultArray = await Manager.GetResultArray();
    Parallel.ForEach(resultArray , result=> //Error here
    {
        SomeMethod(result)); // SomeMethod cast result to Produc class and add to products list
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at these two. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007593/getting-exception-when-working-with-list-and-parallel-loops https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362023/destination-array-not-long-enough/14118859

Comment: Can you please add code for your `SomeMethod` and `Result` class?

Comment: @GuruStron I can't put the exact code but added some changes...hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is not an thread safe collection, which you are trying to update from multiple threads. You can try to use [`ConcurrentBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1) in this case:

```
var products = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();
Result[] resultArray = await Manager.GetResultArray();
Parallel.ForEach(resultArray , result=> //Error here
{
    SomeMethod(result)); // SomeMethod should add to ConcurrentBag
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks Guru, I didn't know the List is not a thread safe.
Could you please explain why the List is not a thread safe?